# Nodejs - xmlhttprequest promise never finish

Tags: promise, xmlhttprequest

module.js

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');


function fetchdata(id) {
    var url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + id;

    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url);

        xhr.onload = function() {
            var jsonStr;
            try {
                fulfill(xhr.response);
            } catch (e) {
                reject(jsonStr);
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function(e) {
            reject(e);
        };
        xhr.send('');
    });
}

module.exports = {
    getdata: function (videoID) {
      return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
        if (!videoID) {
          reject(new Error('Unable to get video id.'));
          return;
        }
        fetchdata(videoID).then(
          function (d) {
            console.log( d);
          }
        );
      });
    }
};
```

index.js

```
var parser = require('./module.js');
parser.getdata("ZI4tRn4dOGg", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
)
```

I tried to get youtube view page source code with xmlhttprequest.
BUT above code does not finish. I guess it is waiting for something. 
Is problem from bluebird? or xhr2? and why does this code never finish?

Comment: are you willing to use a different request libray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `xhr` instance had a memory leak, might be a problem with the library, last publish was a year ago. `Bluebird` was ok. You can fix the hangup by using `node-fetch` and dropping in this replacement for `fetchdata`

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

function fetchdata(id) {
  var url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + id;
  return fetch(url).then(res => res.text())
}
```